# Integration of ACH api with c# on in ewallet withdrawal requests

Tags: c#, .net, api

i Want to integrate ACH api in our Project of webform(nop commerce).

i have credentials provided by https://www.capterra.com/p/164541/GMS-Payment-Processing/
Reply from Gulf Management Systems, Inc.
•   api_id: GMS******
•   api_key: B*****-7***-4***-B***-F********
•   gms_id: 3**

If you are to send disbursements you must submit PBF records via SubmitPBFSetup, generate a file with the PBF id to transaction amount pairs, and submit the file via SubmitFile or SubmitFile_String. I am attaching the PBF file layout. Other details are in the API documentation regarding the above mentioned methods. If you need further assistance, please ask.

Comment: Have you written any code for this? You need to share the code here and also explain what issue you are facing.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Actually i am not clear about ACH Api so want to know or can any one share any URL for reference..Thanks a ton in advance

Comment: hello can you share URLs and any references,i need to integrate in our websites.